# Role based logo and UI in wss 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, 2007, branding, theme

I have to show user based logo and UI in wss 3.0. How can i do this? Can I customize master page or theme for users? Is there inbuilt option for this? It would be better if I could do this without programming.

Suppose I have 3 users and I would like to show their logo on login. they have their own logo.

Comment: Do you mean you want to customise the theme depending on the user role? Please clarify.

Comment: yes, It would be better if theme is customized as per user.

Answer (score 1):

This type of customisation will be very difficult to do without any programming.

I believe that this can be done however, with a custom masterpage in SharePoint Designer 2007, but there needs to be someway of identify the role of the current user. Once that role has been identified, by whatever method, then you can apply custom CSS files to apply different branding for the different users.

Are you able to be any more specific in your requirement? How do users differ, how do you tell SharePoint what user belongs to what role?

Comment: OK Let me know the easiest way to do this thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not something you will use for this specific solution, but you might want to check out *Audiences*
With an Audience, you can create a 'group' of people (picked by some common parameter). In several webparts you can set which Audience should see the webpart. Don't know if the picture webpart allows such things, but you might find this interesting.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx

Comment: Huh, you could use CSS to position the logo to ovelap the default using accurate absolute positioning parameters. Then CEWP is the way to go.